# iOS5: best practices in building an app using tableviewcontrollers

Tags: ios5, uitableview, storyboard

I'm building this app about my city. I'm using a tabbarcontroller with 4 tabs: "What to do, Where to eat, Where to stay and Services". For example, if I go to "Where to eat" a tableviewcontroller shows a table with "Table service", "Counter service", "Snaks", etc. Going into table services, you get "Italian", "Mexican", etc. So as you can see, I have a lot of tables to show everything I want. And my storyboard is getting pretty slow (too many scenes). The question is, is this the correct way to creat an app like this? I'm attaching a screenshot of my storyboard so you guys have an idea of what does it look like. All the scenes are tableviewcontrollers, except the root whitch is a tabbarcontroller.[image]

Comment: Can you please upload hi-res version of that image? 
Skitch is very good software for share images...
Then we can see your table in details

Comment: The tables are created dinamicaly with plist files, or arrays, when they have few items. What I want to know is if I can use only one tableviewcontroller per level, and load the different items programaticaly. Something like: if Italian, load Italian.plist... using the same controller.

Comment: Of cause you can. Use `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this tutorial will be useful for you:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1